# How can this equation be true?

Tags: calculus

I'm currently stuck on an equation that no matter what numbers I insert to it is true, but I can't prove that is true. The equation is:
 $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\frac{(u+v)^2}{(1+\frac{vu}{c^2})^2}}{c^2}}}=(1+\frac{vu}{c^2})*\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{c^2}}}*\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

So I was hoping someone could show me how this equation is actually true. The only thing I have been able to derive so far is: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\frac{(u+v)^2}{(1+\frac{vu}{c^2})^2}}{c^2}}}=(1+\frac{vu}{c^2})*\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{vu+vc+uc}{c^2}}}*\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{vu-vc-uc}{c^2}}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\frac{(u+v)^2}{(1+\frac{vu}{c^2})^2}}{c^2}}}=(1+\frac{vu}{c^2})*\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{c^2}}}*\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} \iff$$

$${\sqrt{1-\frac{\frac{(u+v)^2}{(1+\frac{vu}{c^2})^2}}{c^2}}}=\frac{1}{(1+\frac{vu}{c^2})}*{\sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{c^2}}}*{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} \iff$$

$$ 1-\frac{\frac{(u+v)^2}{(1+\frac{vu}{c^2})^2}}{c^2}=\frac{1}{(1+\frac{vu}{c^2})^2}*(1-\frac{u^2}{c^2})*(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}) \iff $$

$$ c^2-\frac{(u+v)^2}{(1+\frac{vu}{c^2})^2}=\frac{c^2}{(1+\frac{vu}{c^2})^2}*(1-\frac{u^2}{c^2})*(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}) \iff $$

$$ c^2(1+\frac{vu}{c^2})^2-(u+v)^2=c^2*(1-\frac{u^2}{c^2})*(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}) \iff $$

$$ c^4(1+\frac{vu}{c^2})^2-c^2(u+v)^2=c^4*(1-\frac{u^2}{c^2})*(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})  \iff$$

$$ (c^2+vu)^2-c^2(u+v)^2=(c^2-u^2)(c^2-v^2)$$

Answer (score 2):

Square both sides to get a polynomial equation, clean up, done. (Assuming all relevant quantities are positive, which is probably true 'cos it looks like physics)

Comment: This would certainly work better as a comment.